# What is .sln.docstates file created by Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, productivity-power-tools

Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools Version 10.0.20427.1, updated 10 May 2011, is creating a <solution>.sln.docstates file.

What is purpose of the file?

Should I be checking it into version control?

Comment: I was about to post exactly the same question. I've tried google "sln.docstates" (with double quotes) about 20 minutes ago, but got 0 results. Now I got 2 results, both linked to your question. I haven't seen this file before upgrading to the latest version of Productivity Power Tools today. The wired thing is, this file is 8KB in size for a completely new solution. It is created the first time a solution is closed, and it seems it contains the paths and guids of all of my projects, some of them were opened about a zillion years ago.

Comment: I've posted a question on Productivity Power Tools's discussion forum, not get an answer yet.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Here is what Microsoft have to say about it:

> The .docstates file new in this
>   release of the Pro Power Tools. It is
>   used by the Document Tab Well
>   extension to persist and hydrate the
>   state of the floating tab wells. This
>   information was being stored in the
>   hidden .suo file but we
>   had to move it to a separate file to
>   fix a set of crashing bugs (timing
>   issues). In the next release of the
>   Power Tools we will hide this file by
>   default.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/ (Q&A tab, "Is .sln.docstates file created by Productivity Power Tools?" discussion, post by Chris Dias)

So effectively it is a supplement to the .suo (solution user options) file, and like the .suo file it should not be checked into version control.